# How to send packets to router of specific mac address and getting ack back using android

Tags: android, connection

I'm doing a project to develop an app that determine the position of user using in range WIFI router.

Using the MAC address of router is the only way to determine which router is which so i used it to make a map of position for each router.

By sending packet to specific router in range and have it send back ack, i can get that travel time to calculate the position.

1. The problem is i have to send packets to that router directly without using the network as medium to get the result.Is there a way to achieve that?
2. Or if any is there any alternative way to get that travel time?
   Well if it can not be done please tell me.